# Find largest image

Tags: jquery, image, width

I am using the following to find the image within `.content` and apply it's width to the `.project` parent width.

```
    $('.content').find('img').each(function () {
         var $this = $(this), width = $this.width();
         {
            $(this).closest('.project').css("width", width);
        }
    });
```

My problem is that it doesn't find the *largest* image in the `.content` and sometimes applies a width that is smaller than the largest image and is creating problems with my layout.

Any help would be great. Thanks.

---

*Edit*

Woops, *detail* is wrong, the answers are great! I just need to apply the max width the parent `project` div.

Building off Sudhir's answer.

This doesn't work, should it work?

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
var max_width = 0;
$('.content').find('img').each(function(){
        var this_width = $(this).width();
        if (this_width > max_width) max_width = this_width;
});
$(this).closest('.project').css('width', max_width + 'px');
});
```

Example of the layout. There are many projects.

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="project">
        <div class="content">
            <img src="small.jpg"  height="100" width="100" />
            <img src="large.jpg"  height="400" width="600" />
            <img src="medium.jpg"  height="400" width="600" />

        </div>

        <div class="meta">Other content here.

        </div>
    </div>



    <div class="project">
        <div class="content">
            <img src="small.jpg"  height="100" width="100" />
            <img src="large.jpg"  height="400" width="600" />

       </div>

        <div class="meta">Other content here.

        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I'm having trouble picturing what the layout of the Div's is on your site. Do you have lots of .content divs each with their own .project div? Or is there one .content div with .project divs inside it each with images inside them? Could you post an example of the HTML layout please.

Comment: Yep each .content div has it's own parent .project div as well. Hows that @Tim I hope that makes sense, many .projects within a larger container.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't do this on document ready event. You have to do this on window load because all images must be loaded to get the dimensions.

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $('.project').each(function(){
        var maxWidth = 0;
        $(this).find('.content img').each(function(){
            var w = $(this).width();
            if (w > maxWidth) { 
              maxWidth = w;
            }
        });
        if (maxWidth) {
          $(this).css({width:maxWidth});
        }
    });       
});
```

Comment: Thats great @kitgui.com . My only problem is that if there is no image found it defaults to 0px. Which breaks the layout again. But should I write an additional script to look for projects without images.

Comment: right, my point was to show you it was window load as the main issue, not anything else. you can fix as you need. this is for demonstration purposes. I'll put a boolean for you if you just for shtz and giggles

Comment: Thank you very much, do you know if there is a way to avoid the window load issue?

Comment: Yes, you could put a load event for each image individually and give it context of its ".project" and "maxWidth" by using the data property. This becomes a little tricky if images are cached and don't fire as Chrome sometimes does. The less headache way is to rely on window load but it can seem slower. You could also result to putting divs wrapped around the images and use overflow hidden and give it an expected average dimension. Then you can adjust on load. At least users won't notice as much.

Comment: @kitgui.com If I remember right, you cannot have 'load' events on images in older MSIE versions

Comment: @yunzen  man you gotta see this -> http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/  it basically fixes IE   see the IE9 one. This is amazing man. John Resig refers to this guy for inspiration. He's that good.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean something like this:

```
var max_width = 0;
$('.content').find('img').each(function(){
        var this_width = $(this).width();
        if (this_width > max_width) max_width = this_width;
});
$('.project').css('width', max_width + 'px');
```

Hope it helps

Comment: This works well, except it's applying the same width to each `.project`. Rather than finding the largest image within the project and applying the largest with to that project. Like how `.closest` worked before.

Answer (score 1):

To get maximum width of something just iterate with this function:

```
var getMaxWidth = function ($elms) {
    var maxWidth = 0;
    $elms.each(function () {
        var width = $(this).width();
        if (width > maxWidth) {
            maxWidth = width;
        }
    });
    return maxWidth;
};
```

Comment: You forgot to initialise the `width` variable. :-)

Answer (score 1):

The example in the [jQuery plugin authoring guide](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring) is very similar to what you're looking for:

```
$.fn.maxWidth = function() {
  var max = 0;

  this.each(function() {
    max = Math.max(max, $(this).width());
  });

  return max;
};
```

Use it like so:

```
var maxWidth = $('.content img').maxWidth();
```

Answer (score 1):

This works, I don't know if you want it super compressed though:

```
function findmax() { 
    max=Math.max(max,parseInt($(this).css('width'))); }
function sum() {
    max=0;
    $(this).children('img').each(findmax);
    $(this).parent().css('width',max+'px'); }
var max;
$('.content').each(sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looping through all images, so the width of your container will always be the same as your last image.  You should check the width of the current image and compare it to the width of the widest image found at that point and adjust the width accordingly.

**Edit**

Try this:

```
$('.content').each(function () {
    var max_width = 0;
    $(this).find('img').each(function () {
        if ($(this).width() > max_width) {
            max_width = $(this).width();
        }
    });

    $(this).width(max_width);

});
```

Crazy with the nested `$(this)`'s but I think it should work.